# Proving that $GF(p^n)$ contains a unique subfield isomorphic to $GF(p^m)$ if and only if $m$ is a divisor of $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am looking to prove that $GF(p^n)$ contains a unique subfield isomorphic to $GF(p^m)$ if and only if $m$ is a divisor of $n$.
In the Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness

They say that this statement has been proven by E. H. Moore in 1893.

How to go about proving the theorem? I know first I need to generate a subset, prove that it's a subfield, and then assume they are two and show it's unique.

But how to generate it in the first place? Consider the set of polynomials of the form $x^{p^m}-x=0$? Is there a way to show that it's a subfield without checking all the axioms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the zeros of $x^{p^n}-x$ are exactly the elements of a finite field with $p^n$ elements. Since splitting fields are uniquely determined up to isomorphism, we can write $GF(p^n)$.

First, if $m$ divides $n$, then $p^m-1$ divides $p^n-1$ and moreover $x^{p^n-1}-1$ divides $x^{p^n-1}-1$. Thus $x^{p^m}-x$ divides $x^{p^n}-x$. Hence, $GF(p^m)$ is a subfield of $GF(p^n)$.

Conversely, if $GF(p^m)$ is a subfield of $GF(p^n)$, then $GF(p^n)$ is a vector space over $GF(p^m)$. Thus $p^n = (p^m)^k$ for some $k\geq 1$. Hence, $m$ is a divisor of $n$.

Added comment: Suppose $m$ divides $n$ with $n=km$. Then
$\frac{p^n-1}{p^m-1}= \frac{(p^m)^k-1}{p^m-1} = (p^m)^{k-1} + (p^m)^{k-2} +\ldots+p^m+1$.

Comment: Thank you. By what theorem can we conclude that if $m$ divides $n$ then $p^m-1$ divides $p^n - 1$?

Comment: @Maximus By [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128007/xa-1-divides-xb-1-if-and-only-if-a-divides-b) we can conclude this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much! I will search more thoroughly from now on.

Comment: @Maximus: added comment to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Galois correspondence.   $GF(p^n)$ is a Galois extension of $GF(p)$, which has cyclic Galois group.

(Intermediate) extension fields correspond to subgroups (of the Galois group).  We have a subgroup of order $m\iff m\mid n\iff$ we have an extension field of degree $m$.